Problema al extraer datos de un sitio web dinámico usando Selenium y Python
Estoy desarrollando un script en Python utilizando Selenium para extraer datos de una página web específica que tiene una lista pública de clínicas dentales en España. El objetivo es automatizar el proceso de búsqueda, hacer clic en cada enlace "Ver Detalle" para obtener información detallada de cada centro, extraer datos como el nombre y el email del centro, y guardar estos datos en un archivo CSV.
Detalles de la Página Web
La página web objetivo es https://regcess.mscbs.es/regcessWeb/inicioBuscarCentrosAction.do. En esta página:
Selección de Parámetros: Primero seleccionamos una comunidad autónoma (por ejemplo, Extremadura) y el tipo de centro (por ejemplo, Clínicas Dentales).
Interacción: Hacemos clic en un botón de búsqueda que nos lleva a una lista de centros que cumplen con los criterios seleccionados.
Lista de Centros: Cada centro en la lista tiene un enlace "Ver Detalle" que muestra información adicional cuando se hace clic en él.
Dentro de "Ver detalle" es donde estan los datos que interesan, el email y el nombre de la clínica.
La cosa es que para que funcione bien es fundamental que al volver al listado de las clinicas se le de a "volver al listado", de lo contrario no funciona. hasta ahí todo bien, me guarda el archivo .csv con el correo de la primera fila y perfecto.
El problema es cuando intento que haga lo mismo con la siguiente fila, que entre en detalles, guarde el nombre de la clínica y el email y y vuelva al listado., osea, repetir el proceso.
No hay manera, solo consigo ir una y otra vez al "Ver Detalles" de la misma fila. Y que me
Dejo el código que mejor me ha funcionado por aquí abajo, que es el que guarda el resultado dos veces, el mismo.... por si alguien me puede echar un cable.
Mil gracias de antemano.
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Configurar el servicio de ChromeDriver
service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())

# Inicializar el navegador
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

def extraer_datos_centro():
    nombre_centro_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='caja1']/div[@class='campoSeccionDetalleCentro'][preceding-sibling::div[@class='etiquetaSeccionDetalleCentro ' and text()='Nombre de Centro']]"))
    )
    nombre_centro = nombre_centro_element.text.strip()

    email_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='caja1']/div[@class='campoSeccionDetalleCentro'][preceding-sibling::div[@class='etiquetaSeccionDetalleCentro ' and text()='Email']]")
    email = email_element.text.strip()

    print(f"Nombre del centro: {nombre_centro}")
    print(f"Email: {email}")
    return nombre_centro, email

try:
    driver.get('https://regcess.mscbs.es/regcessWeb/inicioBuscarCentrosAction.do')

    select_comunidad = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'agenteComboId'))
    select_comunidad.select_by_value('20')  # Extremadura

    select_clases_centros = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tipoCentroId'))
    select_clases_centros.deselect_all()
    select_clases_centros.select_by_value('C251')  # Clínicas Dentales

    submit_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.formButon[type="submit"]')
    submit_button.click()

    time.sleep(5)

    centros_data = []

    # Procesar los dos primeros centros
    for _ in range(2):
        detalle_link = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'javascript:detalleCentro')]"))
        )
        detalle_link.click()
        time.sleep(3)

        nombre, email = extraer_datos_centro()
        centros_data.append([nombre, email])

        volver_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input.formButon[value="Volver al Listado"]'))
        )
        volver_button.click()
        time.sleep(3)

    # Escribir los datos en un archivo CSV
    ruta_archivo = 'C:/workspace/crawler_regcess_registro_sanitario/centros.csv'
    with open(ruta_archivo, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Nombre del Centro', 'Email'])
        writer.writerows(centros_data)

    print(f"Se han guardado los nombres y emails de los centros en: {ruta_archivo}")

    input("Presiona Enter para cerrar el navegador...")

finally:
    driver.quit()

